Postgresql query that subtotals based on parsing a separated list
PostgreSQL 14
Assuming this sample data...



Item
Qty




Fruit:Orange
1


Fruit:Orange
2


Fruit:Orange
3


Fruit:Apple
4


Fruit:Apple
5


Mineral:Jade
1


Mineral:Jade
2


Mineral:Talc:Raw
3


Mineral:Talc:Raw
4


Mineral:Talc:Processed
5


Mineral:Talc:Processed
6



...what is the best way to get something like ROLLUP or a recursive query or UNION to do subtotals for each level of the Item value, breaking on the colons? The number of levels (colon separators) for any given item is variable, but I can determine the maximum, if need be.
Desired result (I know ROLLUP would put more nulls in various places, which is fine):



Item
Qty




Fruit:Orange
6


Fruit:Apple
9


Fruit
15


Mineral:Jade
3


Mineral:Talc:Raw
7


Mineral:Talc:Processed
11


Mineral:Talc
18


Mineral
21


NULL
36




That is not what sql is for.

@Jens: Fair enough, and I can do it in the receiving code, but the built-in functions get me close enough that it seemed worth asking. I'm not sure why asking if it's doable gets me downvoted...

I have used recursive strategy, which works in this case, because I decided to generate parent items by removing the last segment.
Result: fiddle
Here is the code to create your table
CREATE TABLE items (
    item TEXT,
    qty INT
);


to insert into the table
INSERT INTO items (item, qty) VALUES
('Fruit:Orange', 1),
('Fruit:Orange', 2),
('Fruit:Orange', 3),
('Fruit:Apple', 4),
('Fruit:Apple', 5),
('Mineral:Jade', 1),
('Mineral:Jade', 2),
('Mineral:Talc:Raw', 3),
('Mineral:Talc:Raw', 4),
('Mineral:Talc:Processed', 5),
('Mineral:Talc:Processed', 6);

The recursive strategy
WITH RECURSIVE item_hierarchy AS (
    SELECT 
        item,
        qty,
        item AS level_item,
        CASE 
            WHEN POSITION(':' IN item) > 0 THEN 
              ARRAY_TO_STRING(TRIM_ARRAY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(item, ':'), 1), ':')
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS parent_item
    FROM items
    
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT
        ih.item,
        ih.qty,
        ih.parent_item AS level_item,
        CASE 
            WHEN POSITION(':' IN ih.parent_item) > 0 THEN 
              ARRAY_TO_STRING(TRIM_ARRAY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(parent_item, ':'), 1), ':')
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS parent_item
    FROM item_hierarchy ih
    WHERE ih.parent_item IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT 
    COALESCE(level_item, 'NULL') AS item,
    SUM(qty) AS qty
FROM item_hierarchy
GROUP BY level_item
ORDER BY 
    LENGTH(COALESCE(level_item, '')) ASC, 
    level_item;


@ValNik this is what I am seeing....
ims.png

I do not see row ('Mineral:Talc', 18)

Agree with @ValNik that it's missing a sublevel, but I see where you're going with this approach.

@DerekRoberts: Looks like you're being a bit too aggressive about parsing off the parent and always grabbing the first element. I'm seeing if I can adjust it.

@EMF haha! don't I just love the word "aggressive" in this context. the parent was the only idea I could leverage on.   I think you can do this, I believe in you!

I think I got it. Replace LEFT(item, POSITION(':' IN item) - 1) with ARRAY_TO_STRING(TRIM_ARRAY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(item, ':'), 1), ':'). Same with the second instance using ih.parent_item. It doesn't get me the grand total, but that's trivial to UNION on.

@DerekRoberts: If you update your answer, I'll accept it. You got me 99% of the way there!

@EMF awesome sounds good, 99% is A++ . I knew you could do. would do that now DONE!

If try new version of query example - fails on incomplete recursion?(https://dbfiddle.uk/p-P_F_ge)

@ValNik really, I just ran the code and it seems fine... the total isn't what it is like EMF alluded to but it works OR have you maxed out your machine on dbfiddle for the day?

Pls, see simple example (https://dbfiddle.uk/K6Mgwlu_). I will limit recursion depth. And another example(https://dbfiddle.uk/RTCUj3yK).

@ValNik EMF  suggested to use ARRAY_TO_STRING which worked for her, are you saying it doesn't work? I ran this code here(dbfiddle.uk/p-P_F_ge)  and it works so what should be done?

ARRAY_TO_STRING is good function there. I'm about You should use parent_item in recursive part of item_hierarchy:  ARRAY_TO_STRING(TRIM_ARRAY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(parent_item, ':'), 1), ':')

@ValNik ok I will change it now let me know if it is ok

Fwiw, my edits are working for me and producing exactly what I asked for. I tried to post the entire edited snippet but it's too many characters.

But, yeah, it looks like the second instance in the answer is referencing item instead of ih.parent_item.
